# Width of shape and sum of row c++

Tags: c++

I am creating a C++ program to create a width of shape and sum of rows.

The shape works but the sum do not work please could you help me to fix it?
I tried to fix it the middle part looks like work but the top and bottom part do not work. I have tried a couple of things to solve it but could find any solution. I am new on this website as well. If I explained something wrong please let me know I can fix it.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int sum_top = 0;
    int sum_middle = 0;
    int sum_bottom = 0;
    int answer;

    cout<<"This program prints a table with user inputs. After creating the shape the program will calculate the sum of the elements.\n"<<endl;

    do {
        cout<<"Width of the shape? (Enter odd number only): "<<endl;
        cin>>i;
        if (i%2 == 0 ) {
            cout<<"ERROR: Invalid entry of rows.\n\n"<<i<<endl;
        }

        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter row number to get sum: "<<endl;
        cin>>answer;
        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"Answer: "<<endl;

    } while ( i%2 == 0 );

    int j,k,l;

    // print top
    for ( j = 0; j<i/2 ; j++ ) {
        for ( k =0; k< i/2 - j; k++) {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for( l=0; l < (2*j + 1); l++) {
            cout<<l+1;
            sum_top += l;
        }
        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    }

    //print middle
    for( l=1; l<=i; l++) {
        cout<<l;
        sum_middle += l; 
    }
    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
     //print bottom
    for ( j = 0; j<i/2 ; j++ ) {
        for ( k =0; k<j+1 ; k++) {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for( l=1; l < i - (2*j + 1); l++) {
            cout<<l;
            sum_bottom += l;
        }
        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    }

    if(answer == (i/2)+1) {
        cout<<"The sum is "<<sum_top;
    }
    if(answer == (i/2)+1) {
        cout<<"The sum is "<<sum_middle;
    }
    if(answer == (i/2)+1) {
        cout<<"The sum is "<<sum_bottom;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. You generally won't get help unless you provide us with: (1) the expected behavior of your program; (2) the actual behavior of your program along with any error printed by the compiler, linker, or runtime; (3) a [mcve].

Comment: @Blue Could you please elaborate it a bit further what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: what shape and what rows? what is not working?

Comment: Diamond shape with odd numbers and at the end sum of row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *assume* this is what you *were trying* to do.

***Updated Code:***

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int middle_row = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int answer = 0;

    cout<<"This program prints a table with user inputs. After creating the shape the program will calculate the sum of the elements.\n"<<endl;

    do {
        cout<<"Width of the shape? (Enter odd number only): "<<endl;
        cin>>i;
        if (i%2 == 0 ) {
            cout<<"ERROR: Invalid entry of rows.\n\n"<<i<<endl;
        }

        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter row number to get sum: "<<endl;
        cin>>answer;
        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"Answer: "<<endl;

    } while ( i%2 == 0 );

    int j,k,l;

    // print top
    for ( j = 0; j<i/2 ; j++ ) {
        for ( k =0; k< i/2 - j; k++) {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for( l=0; l < (2*j + 1); l++) {
            cout<<l+1;
        }
        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    }

    //print middle
    for( l=1; l<=i; l++) {
        cout<<l;
        }
    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
     //print bottom
    for ( j = 0; j<i/2 ; j++ ) {
        for ( k =0; k<j+1 ; k++) {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for( l=1; l < i - (2*j + 1); l++) {
            cout<<l;
        }
        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    }

    middle_row = (i+1)/2;
    if (answer > middle_row)
    {
        row = middle_row - answer%middle_row - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        row = answer - 1;
    }

    n = 2*row + 1;
    sum = (n*(n + 1))/2;

    cout<<"The sum is "<<sum<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

*Recommendation*: ***Please try to write a clean and modular code.***

p.s: I tried not to modify your code much. (*Although I so wanted to make it clean and modular*)

Comment: Thanks for that I have tried it on my compiler but the sum does not work. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: My program draws a diamond shape with odd numbers
For example:
Width of the shape?(Enter odd number only)
9
Enter row number to get sum
5
ANSWER.
    1
   123
  12345
 1234567
123456789
 1234567
  12345
   123
    1
SUM OF ROW is 45

Comment: @Blue Have you tried my code ? It's working on my compiler (GCC Compiler on Windows 7 machine) 
Can you give me detail about the compiler you are using ?

Comment: The sum section did not work on my compiler is MINGW32. Is that the problem ? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Mohammed I executed online and it gives this error 
bash: line 1:     7 Floating point exception(core dumped) bash -c 'g++ -o jdoodle *.cpp && ./jdoodle'

Comment: @Blue Apologies, I missed one thing. Please see the updated code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helps. I solve the problem. Thanks again bro!